# Build Java InputStream object from Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> in Play Framework to use Google Cloud Storage Blob object

Tags: java, playframework, google-cloud-storage

I have a Play Framework (version 2.5.12) application that grabs a file from the form/request.

I am using code from this example:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFileUpload

I am attempting to pass that file to a custom class built from Google Cloud Storage API library (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

I am using this example in my custom `GoogleStorage` class:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-storage

Since I am getting the file in my controller as a `Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File>` and need to pass that to the custom class, the `Blob` object needs an `InputStream` to create this file up in a storage bucket in Google Cloud.

Here is the controller code getting the file:

```
Http.MultipartFormData<File> formData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
if (formData != null) {     
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> filePart = formData.getFile("fileAttach");

    // InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePart); THIS DOES NOT WORK

    if (filePart != null) {                 
         // Send the file/multipart content to the storage bucket...
        GoogleStorage.sendFileToBucket(filePart); // THIS DOES NOT ALLOW THE FILE PART TO BE PASSED

       ...
    }
}
```

Here is the custom `GoogleStorage` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;

public class GoogleStorage {

    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = System.getenv("BUCKET_NAME");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static String sendFileToBucket(Part filePart) {

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

        // final Part filePart = req.getPart("file");
        final String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();

        // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
        List<Acl> acls = new ArrayList<>();
        acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));
        // the inputstream is closed by default, so we don't need to close it
        // here
        Blob blob = null;
        try {
            blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(BUCKET_NAME, fileName).setAcl(acls).build(),
                    filePart.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return blob.getMediaLink();

    }

}
```

As you can see, I need the `InputStream` object in the line:

```
    blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(BUCKET_NAME, fileName).setAcl(acls).build(),
            filePart.getInputStream());
```

but when I add this line to my controller code:

```
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePart);
```

It causes an error

`The constructor FileInputStream(Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File>) is undefined`

and says the fix is to

`Change type of 'filePart' to 'String'`

which does not work either.

Since it seems I am restricted to the `InputStream` object to create the `Blob` object, is there a way to convert the `Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File>` to an `InputStream` object?  Or is there a better way to get the file over to the custom class?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little deeper, the fix was to get the full file path and create a InputStream from that:
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fullFilePath);

and pass the InputStream and file name to the custom class.

So, my code now looks like this:

```
Http.MultipartFormData<File> formData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
if (formData != null) {     
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> filePart = formData.getFile("fileAttach");
    if (filePart != null) {                 
        fileName = filePart.getFilename().trim();
        // Is there a file?
        if (!fileName.equals("") && fileName != null) {
            Logger.info("AdultPTPController: File Name = " + fileName);                     
            fileContentType = filePart.getContentType();
            file = filePart.getFile();
            long size = Files.size(file.toPath());                      
            String fullFilePath = file.getPath();                   
            InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fullFilePath);                     
            // Send the file stream and file name to the storage bucket...
            GoogleStorage.sendFileToBucket(fileStream, fileName);

        ...
    }
}
```

And the custom class looks like this:

```
public static String sendFileToBucket(InputStream fileStream, String fileName) throws IOException {

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // Modify access list to allow all users with link to read file
    List<Acl> acls = new ArrayList<>();
    acls.add(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));
    // the inputstream is closed by default, so we don't need to close it
    // here
    Blob blob = null;
    blob = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(BUCKET_NAME, fileName).setAcl(acls).build(),
            fileStream);

    return blob.getMediaLink();
}
```

Comment: You should accept your answer so that this question appear as solved.